# System of equations $F(\mathbf x)=\mathbf c$ has unique solution for any $\mathbf c$, then $F$ is strictly monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, monotone-functions

Function $F=(f_1,f_2)$. $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable real functions $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. Consider a system of equations:

$$f_1(x_1,x_2)=c_1$$
$$f_2(x_1,x_2)=c_2$$

What is the sufficient and necessary condition of that $x$ has unique solution for any $c$?

One may conjecture that $(x'-x)(F(x')-F(x))>0$ or $<0$ for any $x\neq x'$.

---

We know that in one dimension, To ensure that $g(x)=c$ have a unique solution for any constant $c$, $g$ must be either strictly increasing or decreasing. Does this idea extend to multi-variate functions?

Comment: You might be interested in the inverse function theorem. Also, this isn't functional analysis.

Comment: @qbert I guess the inverse function theorem works only on a neighborhood set but not the entire domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering a differentiable function $F: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$.

You are asking if there is a unique solution of $F$ for any element in the target set $\mathbb R^2$.

Hence $F$ must be both injective and surjective.

So $F$ must be a differentiable bijective map from $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$. Don't complicate yourself with $f_1$ and $f_2$s.

If you think about it, isn't that exactly what monotonicity says in 1D functions?

Comment: Given that $F$ is bijective, if we fix $x_1$, then $F$ must be strictly monotonic in $x_2$; if we fix $x_2$, then $F$ must be strictly monotonic in $x_1$. So the strict monotonicity of the partial function of $F$ is one of the necessary conditions of bijectivity. Just one cent please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I don't think I can argue with that observation. However some of the expressions you used-- I have never heard of them before. I'm willing to bet you might be correct though.